# Flutter firebase_auth package URI not found

Tags: flutter

I'm attempting to import the firebase_auth package like so

```
import 'package:flutter_firebase_auth/user_dashboard.dart';
```

However,my debugger says that the URI is not found.
Is it possible that this API was removed?

Comment: Where did you get that import. There is no package `flutter_firebase_auth` on pub.dartlang.org and `firebase_auth` doesn't export a file `user_dashboard.dart`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was attempting to create a test app,and that's what was used in the example code. I think `user_dashboard.dart` is a class I was supposed to create later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only valid import for `firebase_auth` is

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

I Know im too late just faced this issue and its solution was pretty easy:
just add these 3 lines in terminal (In Visual Studio Code)

```
 $ flutter pub add firebase_auth
```

{This will add a line like this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` (and run an implicit `flutter pub get`):

```
dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.3
}
```

Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

After writing those lines in terminal everything will work:

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share this due to it being extremely odd. But if you're using Android Studio and getting this error. *This is taking into consideration that all your files are correct including your pubspec.yaml*

**Use Visual Studio Code**

Run "flutter clean" and fire up your emulator from VS Code. This fixed the issue for me.